# Android-Open Navigation Drawer just with Click on AppIcon

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

There is a way to disable the navigation drawer to open with a swipe?
I have a Swipe to dismiss ListView and sometimes the user trigger the navigationDrawer while he want to delet an item of the list.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

Comment: When I use it I disable swipe gestures to open and close. There is a way to disable just to open?

Comment: not really, this disables all the actions from the user you can't pick which

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Comment: When I use it I disable swipe gestures to open and close. 
There is a way to disable just to open?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prevent the drawer to be opened by swipe and close normally This Is the Trick!

```
       // Drawer Layout
        final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.hello_world, R.string.action_settings){

            @Override
            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                Log.d("here","close");
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            }
            @Override
            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                Log.d("here","open");
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

the tricky part is, you should lock the drawer when it is close and unlock it again when it is open!